# Initialize simple pointer to var vs. reference to pointer to var

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
int main()
{
    int var = 10;

    int *const simple_ptr = &var;
    int *const &ptr_ref = &var;

    int * &bad_ptr_ref = &var; // ERROR: cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int *&'
}
```

Given the code above, what's the difference between `simple_ptr` and `ptr_ref` (except for the obvious)?

Checked with both VC 2015 `/W4` and GCC 7.1 `-Wall`, so `ptr_ref` seems a valid construct.

Is it a reference to some temporary pointer that the compiler generates by any chance?
Since looking at the assembly code generated can see double the instructions for defining `ptr_ref`, and two `lea` instructions respectively:

```
    int *const simple_ptr = &var;
00E4220F  lea         eax,[var]  
00E42212  mov         dword ptr [simple_ptr],eax  
    int *const &ref_ptr = &var;
00E42215  lea         eax,[var]  
00E42218  mov         dword ptr [ebp-30h],eax  
00E4221B  lea         ecx,[ebp-30h]  
00E4221E  mov         dword ptr [ref_ptr],ecx
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Split it in several separate questions.

Comment: About (4): It's the same not only for pointers. `const` references can be bound to any expression, but non-const ones can be bound to lvalues only.

Comment: How is it too broad, the main question is what's the difference between the two definitions in this specific case and this case alone.

Comment: @sharyex You ask 4 different questions (we do one question per question here)

Comment: It was just one question, the additional ones were just to emphasize the kind of answer and explanations I'm looking for, they were all referring to the same thing. Edited.

Comment: For number 4:  It doesn't have to be a pointer to const, it has to be a const pointer to variable (or const).  It's the pointer that mustn't change, not the thing it points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Giving the code above, what's the difference between simple_ptr and ptr_ref (except for the obvious)?

The difference is that `simple_ptr` is a immutable pointer to `var` while `ptr_ref` is a `const &` to the pointer you create when you do `&var`.  Both of these do the same thing though, they will only ever "point" to `var`.

> Is it a reference to some temporary pointer that the compiler generates by any chance?

Yes, exactly.  The `operator &` (ignoring overloading) returns a pointer to the object applied to.  That pointer is returned by value making it a prvalue.  You cannot bind to that with a normal lvalue reference which is why `int * &bad_ptr_ref = &var;` fails.  But, since `ptr_ref` is a `const` lvalue reference, it will bind to that temporary and extend it's life until the reference goes out of scope.